# A way to separately activate WiFi and Mobile Data internet connection

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-data, internet, google-pixel, quick-settings

In my Android 14 (stock/Pixel 7) (it was the same when it was Android 13 before the update), I can activate and deactivate the internet connection via Mobile Data and WiFi. What bothers me is that I have to do two taps.

[image: Settings #1] [image: Settings of Internet]

Is there a way to have Mobile Data and WiFi connection as separate options instead of one? I remember that this was possible on a Huawei with Android 9 flavour.

Comment: It's possible if your device is rooted or if you use Shizuku using [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.casperverswijvelt.unifiedinternetqs) //I've seen some LSPosed module for this but haven't tried it//AFAIK, without root it's not possible since you are attempting to change the OS behavior. See [Behind the scenes looks at the new Internet tile](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/132446941/behind-the-scenes-looks-at-the-new-internet-tile?hl=en) for Google's rationale

Comment: [Shizuku](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=moe.shizuku.privileged.api), if you don't want to root your phone//app claims to work with this. Not tested by me since my device is rooted//Reference my first comment

Comment: To supplement beeshyams' comment, [this change has been applied since Android 12](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-android-12-internet-quick-settings-tile-reasoning/).